# implementing slam on differential drive robot

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, kinect, differential-drive

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,

```
 I want to implement SLAM on a wheel chair equipped with kinect and encoders for extracting the odometry information, there are many packages available for salm on ros as i don't have any experience with them i don't know how to proceed or which package would be better for this, I would be great full for any help.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64111/implementing-slam-on-differential-drive-robot/) by [akhil](https://answers.ros.org/users/2787/akhil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2013-05-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your setup sounds like it is pretty close to the standard setup of the Turtlebot. This [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Build%20a%20map%20with%20SLAM) provides a quick overview of how a map can be generated with the Turtlebot. Of course, your hardware setup differs, so you'll probably want to read some other Turtlebot tutorials from [here](http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot/Tutorials) to get a better understanding of how everything works.

That being said, mapping using the Kinect + gmapping can be relatively brittle depending on the environment you're operating in.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [akhil](https://answers.ros.org/users/2787/akhil/) on 2013-06-01**:
thanks for your response , can I use hector slam for this ?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2013-06-02**:
hector slam does not work well with the Kinect as it has a too small FOV and too much noise. Making it work would require significant code changes.